# Ore's type condition to conclude $G$ has a $k$−factor

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, reference-request

$\textbf{Dirac's Theorem:}$ A simple graph with $n \ge 3$ vertices is Hamiltonian if every vertex has degree $\ge \frac n2$.

$\textbf{Ore's Theorem:}$ A simple graph with $n \ge 3$ vertices is Hamiltonian if and only if for every pair of non-adjacent vertices, the sum of their degrees is $n$ or greater, i.e. $d(x) + d(y) \ge n$.

A $k$−factor is a spanning subgraph $H$ of $G$ in which every member of $H$ has degree $k$.

There are many generalizations of Ore’s Theorem.

Are there any generalizations of Ore’s Theorem and Dirac's Theorem from which we can conclude that $G$ has a $k$−factor?

Comment: Every graph has a a $0$-factor. Hamiltonian graph always has a $2$-factor. For even $n$ it also has a $1$-factor. So for $k \le 2$ we already have some conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tadashi Iida and Tsuyoshi Nishimura in their work [An Ore-Type Condition for the Existence of $k$-Factors in Graphs](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01787640) have exactly what you are asking for.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $k$ be a positive integer, and let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ with $n \ge 4k - 5$, $kn$ even and $\delta \ge k$. If $\deg_G(u) + \deg_G(v) \ge n$ for all pairs of nonadjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ of $V(G)$, then $G$ has a $k$-factor.

> **Theorem 2.** Let $k$ ($k > 0$) be an odd integer, and let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ with $n \ge 4k - 2$, $n$ even and $\delta \ge k$. If $\deg_G(u) + \deg_G(v) \ge n - 1$ for all pairs of nonadjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ of $V(G)$, then $G$ has a $k$-factor.

A bit later Tsuyoshi Nishimura in [A degree condition for the existence of $k$-factors](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jgt.3190160205) gets a condition of different kind:

> **Main Theorem.** Let $k$ be an integer such that $k \ge 3$, and let $G$ be a connected graph of order $n$ with $n \ge 4k - 3$, $kn$ even, and minimum degree at
> least $k$. Suppose that
> $$\max\{\deg(u), \deg(v)\} \ge \frac n 2$$
> for each pair of nonadjacent vertices $u, v$ of $V(G)$. Then $G$ has a $k$-factor.

I can't find the original paper Nash-Williams conditions and the existence of $k$-factors by T. Niessen. But Sizhong Zhou in [Some new sufficient conditions for graphs to have fractional $k$-factors](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00207161003681286?needAccess=true) cites it as

> **Theorem 1.** Let $k \ge 2$ be an integer and $G$ a graph with $n$ vertices. Assume that if $k$ is odd, then $n$ is even and $G$ is connected. Let $G$ satisfy
> $$n > 4k + 1 − 4\sqrt{k + 2},$$
> $$\delta(G) \ge \frac{(k − 1)(n + 2)}{2k − 1} \text{ and}$$
> $$\delta(G) > \frac{1}{2k − 2}((k − 2)n + 2\alpha(G) − 2).$$
> Then $G$ has a $k$-factor.

In the same work Sizhong Zhou generalizes this result for fractional $k$-factor in two ways.

P. S. Here $\delta(G)$, or just $\delta$, means minimum vertex degree in the graph $G$, while $\alpha(G)$ is independence number of the graph $G$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! for the info. Do you know similar results for Dirac's Theorem?

Comment: @User8976 Tsuyoshi Nishimura's main theorem is somewhat close to Dirac's condition. Note that minimum degree at least $k$ is obviously necessary condition for $k$-factor existence.